# weird while($tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php

I have a weird problem. i fetch some rows from database using:

```
while($tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tags))
{
    $return['threads'][] = "<a id='showtag' href='answer.php?view=tag&id=" . $tag['id'] . "&name=" . $tag['name'] . "'>" . $tag['name'] . "</a><a class='addtag' id='" . $tag['id'] . "' href=''> +</a><br />";
}
```

this should provide 2 links (one for entering the tag, and one + for adding the same tag to favourite list).

then i simply wants to display them.

```
foreach($return['threads'] as $key1)
{
    print_r($key1);
}
```

but what i get is:

```
linux +
mac +
```

looks great so far. 'linux' links to:

```
answer.php?view=tag&id=131&name=linux
```

but the problem is that the + sign to the right links to:

```
answer.php?view=tag&id=77&name=mac
```

and 'mac' links to

```
answer.php?view=tag&id=131&name=mac
```

while + sign:

```
answer.php?view=tag&id=77&name=mac
```

The problem is the + sign. it should just show answer.php (i will couple jquery to its class) because i had nothing in href=''. and not another tag's id. when i delete

```
 ...</a></a... to </aa
```

then the problem is gone. but then i had just one link. i want to have one tag link and another link to add the tag link to favourite list.

what could the problem be?

any idea?

Comment: If the plus sign has no href or name, why are you wrapping it in an anchor?

Comment: because it is coupled to jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys.

i returned to many uneccassary (difficult word to spell) unwanted information from database.

i had

```
 SELECT *. solved it by
 tags.*
```

Answer (score 1):

`href=''>` is the issue in the addtag `<a>`. I think `id=77` is probably showing because you have no `href`. You need to look at the source to find the problem - the browser will just confuse you if you look at where it's linking to.

Can you show us the source of the generated links?

Comment: what do you mean with source?

Comment: Right-click - view source. The actual HTML used to show the page.